# Runtime Error LeetCode — 338. Counting Bits in c

Tags: c

The source of question:[LeetCode — 338. Counting Bits in c](https://leetcode.com/problems/counting-bits/)

The introduce:
Given a non negative integer number num. For every numbers i in the range 0 ≤ i ≤ num calculate the number of 1’s in their binary representation and return them as an array.

Example:For num = 5 you should return [0,1,1,2,1,2].

Follow up:

It is very easy to come up with a solution with run time O(n*sizeof(integer)). But can you do it in linear time O(n) /possibly in a single pass?

Space complexity should be O(n).

My code,appear Runtime Error when input 8(sometime 7), the result printf is true:

```
int* countBits(int num, int* returnSize) {
    *returnSize=num+1;
    int*arr=(int*)malloc(num+1);
    arr[0]=0;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<num+1;i++){
        arr[i]=arr[i&(i-1)]+1;
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Rather than `int*arr=(int*)malloc(num+1);`, use `int* arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * (num+1u));`

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating enough memory.  You're currently allocating `num+1` bytes, but what you really want is space for `num+1` values of type `int`.  So you need to multiply by the size:

```
int *arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*(num+1));
```