# Run-Time Check Failure #4 - Stack area around _alloca memory reserved by this function is corrupted?

Tags: c++, stack, runtime-error, alloca

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>

void print_vals(int n)
{
    int *arr = (int *)alloca(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = i;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';

    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print_vals(5);
    print_vals(10);
}
```

When I run this code, I get this error per call:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #4 - Stack area around _alloca memory reserved by this function is corrupted
```

[image]
I'm using Visual C++ 2019, both stdc++14 and stdc++17 produce the same error.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Why are you using raw c-style memoiry  management in c++ at all? Any reasoning for that?

Comment: This code screams out loud to use a simple `std::vecor<int>`in c++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because visual c++ does not allow VLA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Runtime Error LeetCode — 338. Counting Bits in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156344/runtime-error-leetcode-338-counting-bits-in-c)

Comment: @StackExchange123 Huh what? What does a `std:vector<int>` to do with a VLA? Mind to elaborate please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is a reply to the first comment, not the third. As of for `std::vector`, it allocates on the heap. if I wanted to allocate on the stack and still use VLA, I think this is my only choice.

Comment: @StackExchange123 Hmm, OK. That seems to make sense somehow. Otherwise you would need to implement your own as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049657/stack-buffer-based-stl-allocator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to assume this is just sample code since, if your intent is just to *print* the numbers `0..n`, there's absolutely *no* reason why you would use an array for this :-)

---

On to your actual problem, the `alloca` function, like `malloc`, allocates a number of *bytes.* If you then treat it as if you have a number of `int` values (which are almost certainly larger than a byte), that won't end well. That's actually confirmed in the dialog box you see where the size is ten but each array element takes up four:

```
Size: 10
Data: <> 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00
         \_________/ \_________/ \____
            arr[0]      arr[1]      ar
```

What you would need to do is something like:

```
int *arr = (int*) alloca(n * sizeof(*arr)); // n ints, not bytes.
```

---

In any case, I would be *avoiding* `alloca` because:

1. It's really not standard; and
2. It has the annoying habit of misbehaving if it cannot allocate the space, rather than raising an exception as `new` would.

On that last point, the [Linux doco for `alloca`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) states (my emphasis):

> The alloca() function returns a pointer to the beginning of the allocated space. ***If the allocation causes stack overflow, program behavior is undefined.***

If you want something where you don't have to worry about de-allocating it yourself, modern C++ has smart pointers, so you could use something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[n]);
```

When that `arr` variable goes out of scope, the memory that was allocated for it will be automagically released. You can try that in this complete variation on your original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void print_vals(size_t n) {
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr(new int[n]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = static_cast<int>(i);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    print_vals(5);
    print_vals(10);
}
```

As an aside, you'll notice I've also changed to using `size_t` rather than `int` for the size and indexes - I believe that's a better fit. Now, granted, this uses the *heap* rather than the stack, but it's the safer way to do it, based on the earlier comments about `alloca`.

You *could* make `alloca` a little more likely to succeed if you guaranteed some limit on the size, such as with:

```
void print_vals(size_t n) {
    if (n >= 100) {
        doSomethingIntelligent();
        return;
    }
    int *arr = (int *)alloca(n * sizeof(*arr));

    ...
}
```

But that doesn't actually *guarantee* its safety and, if you're going to do that, you may as well use a fixed buffer anyway since you'll *know* the maximum size:

```
void print_vals(size_t n) {
    int arr[100];
    if (n >= sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)) {
        doSomethingIntelligent();
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

---

One other solution I'd like to put forward: if your intent is to be as efficient as possible, you could use a hybrid approach. By that, I mean using a local buffer for *below* a certain size and allocating memory only if needed:

```
void print_vals(size_t n) {
    // Default to using local buffer.

    int localBuff[100];
    int *arr = localBuff;

    // If more space needed, allocate  an auto-freeing smart pointer.

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> allocBuff;
    if (n >= sizeof(localBuff) / sizeof(*localBuff)) {
        allocBuff.reset(new int[n]);
        arr = allocBuff.get();
    }

    // Here, arr points to to a big-enough buffer.

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that... But why does it print the right values tho?

Comment: @StackExchange123, you're doing undefined behaviour. That means undefined as in "it may even *work,* at least for a time" :-) What's probably happening is that it's freely writing to, and reading from, memory outside of the allocated space but, when it comes time to exit the function, corruption has occurred. You're actually *lucky* it caught it rather than using possibly corrupt return values on the stack to return to `main`.

Comment: It annoys me that we have to specify stuff like *which are almost certainly larger than a byte* Can't we just make everything 512 bits and be done with it?

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm using it because VLAs are not allowed in visual c++. Is there any other way?

Comment: @StackExchange123: I've added some other options for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of function[`alloca()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=vs-2019) is *bytes* to allocate, so the size of element must be multiplied to the number of elements.

It can be done like this:

```
int *arr = (int *)alloca(sizeof(*arr) * n);
```